# Limit Within A Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a messages table that can contain the primary message, as well as sub-messages. What i want to achieve is only get the top 2 most recent sub-messages.

```
SELECT message.id, message.date_sent,message.object_id, message.content, 
       SubMessage1.content, SubMessage1.id, SubMessage1.date_sent,
       SubMessage2.content, SubMessage2.id, SubMessage2.date_sent
  FROM messages As Message 
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT messages.object_id as object_id, messages.content as content,
                messages.id as id , messages.date_sent as date_sent
           FROM messages
          ORDER
             BY messages.date_sent ASC LIMIT 1,1
       ) as SubMessage1
    ON Message.id = SubMessage1.object_id
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT messages.object_id as object_id, messages.content as content,
                messages.id as id , messages.date_sent as date_sent
           FROM messages
          ORDER
             BY messages.date_sent ASC LIMIT 2,1
       ) as SubMessage2
    ON Message.id = SubMessage2.object_id
 WHERE Message.id = 1
```

When I remove the limit, I always get the first result. But when I put in the limit I get null values. Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Do you need the results in one row? Would it be ok to have them in 3 rows?

Comment: Yeah. Original Query has 30+ columns. With 10+ joins. It's a massive message feed. I could do it with 3, but then i would have to go through the results and sort that massive mess of duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = 1
Union all
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE object_id=1
ORDER BY date_sent ASC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Make that `LIMIT 0,2` or `LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0` or just `LIMIT 2`.

Comment: I don't want them in 2 different rows. My original query returns 30+ columns. I'm trying to keep the sub comments in the same row or I'll duplicate data all over. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Select only the columns you want. This is the right solution. Now imagine if the customer wants not two but three comments, and if five?

Comment: There are many columns I need for the primary message, but so few i need for the sub. But i get what you're saying. The primary message has groups(circles) attached to it. Subs don't. It's very similar to google circles. You can pick groups or individual users to share the message with. Sub messages don't have these joins between tables.... So what is the difference between having null values for the sub message with your solution, or having null sub message values in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` in the subqueries is being applied *before* the `ON Message.id = ... .object_id` in the joins. As a result, the joins only have the chance to examine *one* message and determine if it's a submessage. Most of the time, it won't be, so you'll get `NULL` values.

To fix this, you need to move the content of your `ON`-clauses into `WHERE`-clauses inside the subquery. Normally that would be a bit of a mess, but since you're only looking to retrieve a single-record result-set, it's not too bad:

```
SELECT message.id, message.date_sent, message.object_id, message.content, 
       SubMessage1.content, SubMessage1.id, SubMessage1.date_sent,
       SubMessage2.content, SubMessage2.id, SubMessage2.date_sent
  FROM messages AS Message 
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT messages.object_id AS object_id, messages.content AS content,
                messages.id AS id, messages.date_sent AS date_sent
           FROM messages
          WHERE messages.object_id = 1
          ORDER
             BY messages.date_sent ASC LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS SubMessage1
    ON TRUE
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT messages.object_id AS object_id, messages.content AS content,
                messages.id AS id, messages.date_sent AS date_sent
           FROM messages
          WHERE messages.object_id = 1
          ORDER
             BY messages.date_sent ASC LIMIT 2,1
       ) AS SubMessage2
    ON TRUE
 WHERE Message.id = 1
;
```

(Note that this includes the parameter three times in the query: less than ideal, perhaps, but really not a problem.)

Comment: I jumped the gun. I know i hard coded the Message.id but in my real query i don't do this. I need the object_id to match the current message.id

Comment: @user1274457: What is the `WHERE` clause in your real query?

Comment: Well think if i wanted to pull all the messages from the table with the attached sub-querry. Your solution is for only pulling 1 message. –

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 rows, use

```
LIMIT 2
```

In SQL land, counting is from 1 not 0.

Also, in mysql LIMIT with 2 params is:

```
LIMIT offset, row_count
```

But with 1 param it's:

```
LIMIT row_count
```

I'd like to meet the genius who decided to move the param like that and kick his in the pants.

Comment: I think the OP understands all that. (S)he's joining a parent record to all-child-records-`LIMIT 1` and all-child-records-`LIMIT 2,1`, so as to get the parent and first two child records all in a single row.

Comment: Yeah, i was screwing around with the limit b/c i thought my syntax was wrong and forgot to change it back. lol. Agreed!

Answer (score -1):

The LIMIT command's starting index is 0. You may want to change your limits to (0, 1) and (1, 1).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. I have 10+ sub comments.